# Crashing after resuming from suspend - Since upgrade to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, suspend, crash, log

I resurrected and old Windows laptop (Dell Vostro 1520) with Ubuntu 12 a while ago. Everything was great (other than my infantile Linux skills) and I went ahead and upgraded to 14.04. Ever since I am unable to resume from a suspend.

Firstly, it takes a long time (30s – 1m?) before I can actually type my password in..

Once I can enter the password, I am logged in however then get presented with crash window(s).

After clearing one of the messages the desktop disappears and a black terminal screen appears momentarily and I end up back at the log in. This sequence of events loops until I shut down with the power button.

Info in the crash window seems to offer different information probably depending on which one I click on (whichever is first as they are loaded over the top of each other).

STUPIDLY I selected the options to ignore the errors in future so now I just get continually kicked out to the login screen with no messages.

I think I recall seeing info about Pulse Audio in one and some Nvidia stuff in another. I think these were the only two.

I am willing to get technical and do the work to find / submit logs etc if someone is willing to give me a bit of a hand regarding which log I'm looking for etc. As mentioned my Linux skills are pretty much novice level at this point however.

many thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems converting very old PC to Ubuntu.  In some cases, it worked, in other ones, not.  In my case, it was a question of ressources.  I finally used the lightweight version of Ubuntu, Lubuntu.  This eliminated the crashes I had and that look similar to the symptoms you describe. My recommandation therefore is to give Lubuntu a try.

Comment: thanks for the response, appreciate the advice. - I'd like to see if I can get a bit further before aborting mission; my other option is going back to 12 which was great. I will use shutdown for as long as my patience persists with attempting to resolve. thx again..